# ui-datepicker laravel validate format

Tags: php, laravel, jquery-ui, date-format

i am using the ui-datpicker de jquery like this way

```
 var dates = $("#datepicker, #datepicker_2").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'DD. d MM. yy',

        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: false,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        minDate: dateToday,
        onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
            var option = this.id == "datepicker" ? "minDate" : "maxDate",
                instance = $(this).data("datepicker"),
                date = $.datepicker.parseDate(instance.settings.dateFormat || $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, selectedDate, instance.settings);
            dates.not(this).datepicker("option", option, date);
        }
    });
```

and i try to validate this date using laravel validator like this :

```
 'date_validation' => 'required|date_format:"l. d F.y"',
```

but it always give me this error

> The date validation does not match the format l. d F.y

.. any help please .. i am stack here

Comment: have you tried `dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"` ?

Comment: Check the format that's being passed in. It may not be what you expect.

Comment: @SagarGautam yes i tried this and it works .. yy-mm-dd or y-M-d .. the standard format it works well but for this one even when i try to do "d F y" it doesn't work

Comment: i try this right now and it works fine .. jquery : `dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',` and in the php `'date_validation' => 'date_format:"d/m/Y"',` and when i try to add the day with only 3 letter like this way  PHP: `'date_validation' => 'date_format:"D d/m/Y"'` and in the datepicker like this  `dateFormat: 'D dd/mm/yy',` it doesn't work .. it maybe because the language or something like that ??

Comment: i try to validate only date with php by writing  `'date_validation' => 'date' ` and when i try jquery date_format: dd/mm/yy i get the error that onlu date is accepted as if it doesn't consider this like a valid date .. euuf confused here . need help please